# Hibernate/JPA Annotations -- Unknown Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

An application that has been working well for months has stopped picking up the JPA `@Entity` annotations that have been a part of it for months.  As my integration tests run I see dozens of "`org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.whatever.OrderSystem`" type errors.

It isn't clear to me what's gone wrong here.

I have no `hibernate.cfg.xml` file because I'm using the Hibernate Entity Manager.  Since I'm exclusively using annotations, there are no .hbm.xml files for my entities.  My `persistence.xml` file is minimal, and lives in `META-INF` as it is supposed to.

I'm obviously missing something but can't put my finger on it.

I'm using hibernate-annotations 3.2.1, hibernate-entitymanager 3.2.1, persistence-api 1.0 and hibernate 3.2.1.  hibernate-commons-annotations is also a part of the project's POM but I don't know if that's relevant.

Is there a web.xml entry that has vanished, or a Spring configuration entry that has accidentally been deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to recall I had a similar issue at one time.

Its a long shot, but if you're not already doing this, have you explicitly specified the provider you are using?

```
<persistence ...>
   <persistence-unit ...>
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> <---- explicit setting
      ....
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Otherwise, I'm not sure?

Comment: This resolved it.  Thank you. I still don't understand why it spontaneously stopped working but I'm happy to have a solution.

Comment: I think it might not have been your hibernate dependency that changed, but perhaps the JPA-persistence API dependency itself. From what I recall, when I updated to a later version of the persistence API, things stopped working?

Comment: It may also be that you might have only had one persistence provider, but a new dependency may have introduced a second persistence provider, which caused JPA to lose its way?

Answer (score 5):

verify in your entity classe that you import javax.persistent.Entity and not org.hibernate.annotations.Entity

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening for one specific class (few classes) or all the entity classes.  The persistence.xml file  has a list of class and or jar files that need to be scanned for @Entity mappings. If it was working earlier you can do a quick diff with the version of persistence.xml  that was working correctly.  Another issue could be that it is picking up a different persistence.xml file - you can verify this by introducing an error (for e.g., make the xml invalid) in  the persistence.xml.